# Getting data from another table with joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I tried some stuff but nothing seems to work, i will explain what it has to do,
First i have 3 mysql tables,

1. tablename: customers
   All info of the customers(name, zipcode, etc)
2. tablename: customers_companies
   Just a customer_id from table customers and company_id from table companies
3. tablename: users_companies
   Just user_id from table users and company_id from table companies

First a user adds there company to the database, it adds user_id and company_id to users_companies
When you add a customer it adds the customer_id and company_id to customers_companies

It has to echo all customers from customers_companies in php but only if you part of the company so first mysql checks the customer_id and gets the company_id from customers_companies
With that company_id is search to all users who are allowed to see the customers in users_companies
When found all users that are allowed it have to get all information about the customers from table customers and echo it in a table in html/php

can someone help me? If you need more information just ask and i will answer

Thanks

EDIT:

```
            <tbody>
            <? $result = mysql_query("SELECT customers.* FROM `customers` LEFT JOIN `customers_companies` ON (`customer`.`id` = `customers_companies`.`company_id`) INNER JOIN `user_companies` (`customers_companies`.`company_id` = `customers_companies`.`company_id`) WHERE `customers_companies`.`bedrijf_id`");?>
            <? $i = 1;?>
            <? while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="align-center"><? echo $i; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= $row['naam']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= $row['adres']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= $row['postcode']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= $row['plaats']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= $row['land']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= 0,$row['telefoon']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="table-icon archive" title="Archive"></a>
                        <a onclick="return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je dit bedrijf  wilt verwijderen? alle gekoppelde items worden ook verwijdert zoals facturen, klanten, enz')" href="user.php?p=bedrijven&del=<?= $row['id'];?>" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <? $i += 1; ?>
            <? endwhile; ?>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Can you show us your query?

Comment: Can you show us the schema?

Comment: And what's the resulting output from your code? Does it output anything? Do you get an error?

Comment: Nothing But i fixed already thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*
       ,cc.*
       ,uc.*
    FROM customers_companies cc
    JOIN customers c
        ON cc.customer_id = c.id
    JOIN users_companies uc
        ON cc.company_id = uc.id
    WHERE uc.id = cc.company_id
```

Something like this?

Comment: Does it give you any output at all?